# How to publish App_Data folder to IIS 8 using MsBuild?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, msbuild, windows-server-2012, iis-8

I am using a TeamCity build that has been working for the past several years on IIS 7.5 installations. I have recently upgraded to IIS 8 and I am finding that the App_Data directory is not being deployed when I execute my MsBuild script.

Our TeamCity build deletes the entire IIS site directory contents during each publish to ensure that we start with a clean slate and don't have an lingering files. I need to continue to do this but now all of the sudden I can longer automatically push out the App_Data folder during the publish step. I have even tried adding a dummy Placeholder.txt file to the folder (and set the BuildAction to content in Visual Studio) but the App_Data folder still does not appear on my web server. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... it turns out that all I had to do was add some content to the Placeholder.txt files. Seems like the deployment tools were skipping the files since they were empty.